# If the solution of ODE is null function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

$f: \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continous differentialble with f(t,0)=0 for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\overline{x}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a solution of the ODE $$ x'(t)=f(t,x(t))$$
Prove that there exists a t with $\overline{x}(t)=0$ if and only if when $\overline{x}(t)=0$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$

The direction  $"\Leftarrow"$ is trivial, because $\overline{x}$ is then a null function. But I don't know how to deal with the direction $"\Rightarrow"$. Should I prove that $\overline{x}$ is a globle solution such that $\overline{x}(t)=0$ for all t?

Comment: What is the version of Picard-Lindelöf or Cauchy-Lipschitz that you are to apply? What is is the uniqueness claim in it?

Comment: From what I've learnd and I may write in short: :→ℝis continous and satisfies the condition that f is local lipschitz continous then there is two conclusion:  
1.(local unique existence) For every $(t_0,x_0)$ there existis $\epsilon>0$, such that the IWP $x'=f(t,x),\  x(t_0)=x_0$ has only one solution $x:[t_0-\epsilon, t_0+\epsilon ] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$                                                                         2.(global uniqueness) $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is an interval with $t_0\in I$. If $x_1,x_2:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ are solutions of IWP, then $x_1=x_2$

Comment: Yes. The point 2.) is all you need here, take $I$ as the domain of the hypothetical other solution $\bar x$ that is not constant zero but has a zero point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $t \mapsto 0$ is a solution because of $f(t, 0)= 0$. Because of the continuous differentiability, for every $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ there is *exactly* one solution $x_0$ such that $x_0(t_0) = 0$ (see Picard-Lindelöf Theorem). This solution has already been identified as being constantly $0$. This proves "$\implies$".

Picard-Lindelöf in fact guarantees that *every* othe solution of the ODE does not cross the origin.